# Cassandra - can't understand why this simple setup won't work?

Tags: cassandra

I am a newbie to cassandra. I try those two simple setup: single data center cluster. But I can't understand why the second one won't work?

All nodes are installed cassandra 3.3 with configurations are as link:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html

**SETUP 1:**

- Cluster size of 3 nodes: 192.168.1.201, 192.168.1.202, and 192.168.1.203
- Replication factor of: 2
- Write consistency level of: QUORUM (2 nodes)
- Read consistency level of: QUORUM (2 nodes)

> Datacenter: dc1
>
> ===============
>
> Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
>
> --  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
>
> UN  192.168.1.201  4.57 MB    256          ?      a0138a81-45f9-4df5-af97-362c1bd2e242  rack1
>
> UN  192.168.1.202  1.67 MB    256          ?       e8a73b59-8852-4e3d-951e-bf8e231d6b5f  rack1
>
> UN 192.168.1.203  4.87 MB    256          ?       7b02c94c-14c5-4b34-8a0d-dc16dec8c1f9  rack1

The all 3 nodes are up!

**SETUP 2:**

- Cluster size of 4 nodes - 192.168.1.201, 192.168.1.202, 192.168.1.203, and 192.168.1.204
- Replication factor of: 2
- Write consistency level of: QUORUM (2 nodes)
- Read consistency level of: QUORUM (2 nodes)

> Datacenter: dc1
>
> ===============
>
> Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
>
> --  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
>
> UN  192.168.1.201  3.87 MB    256          ?      a0138a81-45f9-4df5-af97-362c1bd2e242  rack1
>
> UN  192.168.1.202  2.54 MB    256          ?       42bcba40-3941-43af-b694-06c1d4f615cc  rack1
>
> UN  192.168.1.203  3.77 MB    256          ?       7b02c94c-14c5-4b34-8a0d-dc16dec8c1f9  rack1
>
> DN  192.168.1.204  1.67 MB    256          ?       e8a73b59-8852-4e3d-951e-bf8e231d6b5f  rack1

As you can see, node 192.168.1.204 is down (I forced it down for testing purpose), and the other 3 nodes are still up!
But, it wont work. Everytime I run the query, it return with an error (using DevCenter GUI tool):
***"Not enough replicas avaible for query at consistency QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)"***

If I use nodetool to removenode 192.168.1.204, and SETUP 2 becomes SETUP 1 then it works again.

I thinks, the SETUP 2 should run well as the SETUP 1?

Can someone explains why?

Comment: ...yes I answered this **EXACT** question 3 days ago.  -1 for not searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a quorum (more than half) you need the number of replicas / 2 + 1.

You have a 4 node cluster, with 3 up. With a replication factor of 2 you need both nodes up `(2/2+1 = 2 of the 2 replicas)` for a quorum to succeed. If a piece of data you have would belong on the downed node you would not be able to satisfy the quorum requirement so you get that error. With a consistency level of `ONE` it would work however. In order to have 1 node down and still be able to achieve a quorum you need to set the replication factor to at least 3 `(3/2+1 = 2 of the 3 required)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: My cql was: `SELECT * FROM "my_table";`
If I get i right, because the query needs all data, so it caused the error.
What if I only query a piece of data: `SEELCT * FROM "my_table" WHERE "id" = 244860a0-f5c0-4c86-a3c3-89d1b9093bf0;`
Assume that piece of data was not stored in downed node, then the query will run?

Comment: yes, there is a possibility that a partition's 2 replicas could be on the nodes that are up. For high availability you should really use an RF of at least 3 though if planning to use quorum for stronger consistency though.